# Is a Data Adapter always needed?

Tags: sql-server, dataadapter

If have a query that I ONLY want to execute, and have no need to fill any data within a table, then is it necessary to have a data adapter for that purpose?

Comment: `SqlCommand` is ideal for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements as well as `ALTER`, `DROP`, and `CREATE` (there are more like calling a stored proc or getting a data reader etc). The method you are looking for is called `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Yes, because I plan to use INSERT and DELETE queries. Why would SQL write ExecuteNonQuery if a query would actually be executed?

Comment: From the documentation: [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) - `Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.`

Comment: Thanks for your help Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not necessary to use a [SqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx). Its really a bridge between a DataSet and Sql Server.

Instead you can use [SqlCommand - ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
>   objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without
>   using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.
>   Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or
>   return values mapped to parameters are populated with data.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
           "your connection string"))
{
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("your sql", conn)
      {
        conn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```